# Show alert before moving to next tab in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have tabs in my app.In one tab i showing a view controller.in one of the tab i have a view controller which contains text fields for filling a form.So if user has filled the form & not saved it then i want to show an alert.If your click no on alert then it should move to next screen else not.I have tried the following it works but it shows alert on every screen.

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {


  {
      if ([self isAllDataValid])
      {
          back_alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Are you sure you want to delete your data?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
          [back_alert show];

          return NO;
      }
      else
      {
          return YES;

      }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  -(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {

    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    NSLog(@"Tab index = %u (%u)", indexOfTab); 
    if (indexOfTab == 1)
   {
     //add your alert.. 

   }
 }
```

Comment: what to dio with index of tab??? I need to show only alert for current view controller

Comment: actually i want to show alert when text i have filled partial data & i want to move to another tab.I mean to going out only from current tab not coming into the tab

Comment: you can move form this code...& you display alert...when you click on tabbar index then call this method...

Comment: It has not solved muy problem yet.I want to show only alert when moving to another tab from current tab not from any other tab from current tab

Comment: what is the issue..telll me

Comment: the delegate should call for only current view controller but it is called for every view controller

Comment: @deepakkumar you r right..suppose your current tab is 2 then code in 1 tab & 3rd tab

Comment: When alert display then call alert delegate..& check if you want...if data is filled...then chenged tab bar index otherwise nothing

Comment: @deepakkumar please accept as answer...if any error then tell me